# Why is this question about CSS styles opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

The question [If I built an app with a CSS framework, and then they change their styles, would the look of my site change with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813154/if-i-built-an-app-with-a-css-framework-and-then-they-change-their-styles-would) about CSS frameworks was closed as opinion-based.

The question can be answered with facts.

Why is it opinion-based?

Comment: I'd (maybe) close as needs more focus. An edit should be made because otherwise, it's too broad. Which framework? I think it does depend on that. And also it would depend on the website itself, no? But that's my guess.

Comment: 1. There are two questions in that question. 2. The second one is a bit open ended. 3. There are no details how the library is consumed. Your answer assumes they are directly linked from some sort of CDN and there is no versioning. Yet, they can also be downloaded and hosted separately. Or come from `somecdn.com/version/1.2.3/somelibrary.css` in which case your answer doesn't necessarily apply.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this question being closed as opinion-based because it's [an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). The question is also too broad (because listing all of the things that *could* happen would be far too long for a Stack Overflow answer) and lacking in detail (because it's really hard to answer this kind of question without more detail).

Think about it this way: the question is basically asking us to list all of the possible effects of any change in any library to any site. That's not really an answerable question.

Answer (score 3):

Agree that it probably should have been closed as "need more focus" and even the answer to the question agrees with that - it contains two separate unrelated answers titled with "Question 1" and "Question 2".

Why people may have voted as "opinion based" - there are a lot of CSS frameworks and as result one variant of the answer is "I used XYZ framework and found that ..." which is more or less opinion/personal experience about a particular framework. Not every framework is about styles and not every usage of framework leaves all styles original leading to even more variants. There are a lot of options for end-of-life behavior for such frameworks too.

To answer such question I'd recommend editing it to remove all but one of the questions (and advice the author to post separate questions in the comment about the edit) and if possible (i.e. the author commented about a particular framework) narrow down scope so concrete answer can cover whole question.

Comment: It's also an [open-ended, hypothetical question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).